# fullcalendar v4-alpha 3 load the events after GET from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I´ve recently changed my fullcalendar version v3.4 to v4 because there are some new options that i need, but i normally use ajax whenever i need to fetch something and i´m used to it. My problem is, i don´t know how to load the events after getting [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-json-feed) way:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'pt',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Hoje',
            listWeek: 'lista',
        },
        events: {
            url: '/agenda/getEvents',
            method: 'GET',
            extraParams: {
                data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
            },
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```

The events are being fetch correctly, but now what?!, where do i implement a **then** or **success** function in order to load them?

Thanks for your time, regards.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is not clear, but you need to have the result of `/agenda/getEvents` (or `/myfeed.php` from documentation) in a valid JSON format of Event Object's (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-object), example:

```
[
    {
      "id": "a",
      "title": "my event",
      "start": "2018-09-01"
    }
]
```

You can also have custom properties, but you'll then need to use the callback `eventRender` (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) to manipulate the `element` with your `event` data.

There are also other callbacks that may be useful, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-display and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-parsing clarifies it much better.

**Edit**

OP was actually looking for https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function, the v4 version registration of the callback is different from previous versions.

Comment: Thanks(obrigado) for answering, i actually added a success function and passed and argument which i can console.log and see all the events from my database, but now what? i´ve tried a for loop to add the events but nothing seems to work.

Comment: De nada. Umm, `evenRender` should be called on a per event basis, double check if the source format is correct if you're getting more than one event in the `event` argument.

Comment: The thing is, because i will have a lot of events i´m using a for loop....in fullcalendar version 3 you would simply do callback(events) after the for loop because you were inside events function which had a callBack as a parameter...now i dont´t know how to perform this.

Comment: You should limit the number of events as much as possible, filtering by date for example, and you should really use the internal calendar handling for events so you can make use of cache, etc. I guess then JSON is not the source you're looking for :D

Comment: maybe try, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function, you do need to implement you're own method of getting the json, but then you'd be able to iterate the list of events before sending a `successCallback`

Comment: that´s exactlly what i had in version 3 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) inside this function you would do the for loop and at the end simply do callback(arrayofevents);....but now, it says "Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function"

Comment: callback registration has changes, the arguments are now `function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) { }`, so I think you would need to rename `callback`to `successCallback`.

Comment: EXACTLY THAT!!! thanks man for your help and pacience with me...by the way, are you BR or PT ?